# Preview.app Find -> Done keyboard shortcut

Tags: keyboard, macos, preview

I've been able to configure a keyboard driven workflow in Preview.app using [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/) and Keyboard->Shortcuts but there's one situation I can't seem to find a way to avoid using the mouse: `Done` to clear `Find` results.

To clarify:
[image: Figure]

Is it possible to trigger this via the keyboard? I'm on El Capitan (Preview.app version 8.1)

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Esc</kbd>  works for me - no Karabiner necessary.

Comment: I'm not sure the context in which `Esc` works for you but the result of the following steps results in nothing more than an "error" sound:

1. Search for term with `Find` (non fullscreen mode)
2. Press `Esc`

Comment: Open pdf, hit cmd/F, type "test", hit Esc.

Comment: Hmm. Yeah, I don't get the same results. I'm not sure how view options might affect this. My preference is to set the toolbar hidden. I found that if I unhide the toolbar, cmd/F, type "test", cmd/F, Esc will successfully close the results (without pressing cmd/F again, Esc does nothing). Strange.

Comment: yup, needs the toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the extra markup toolbar visible, <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>, then there’s an extra search field visible in which the Escape key <kbd>⎋</kbd> works. So if you’ve hidden that toolbar for some extra vertical content space, use the shortcut to display it, hit escape, then hide the toolbar again.

Compare

[image]

vs

[image]

Related question: [How to end/escape “Find” command via keyboard in macOS Preview app?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/425817/how-to-end-escape-find-command-via-keyboard-in-macos-preview-app)